# Conditional rendering with AND logical operator always returns true in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, logical-operators, conditional-operator, conditional-rendering

I am doing a project where I want to close a dialog after the login is done in a async-await arrow function, for that I call the login function in a button and wait for the return (true if login its complete) and use a logical operator `&&` to close the dialog if true with the hook `onClose`, but the `onClose` gets called anyways, if its true or false, I have spent a full day trying to fix it, what am I doing wrong? Thank you for the help in advance. ^^

**Login arrow async function**

```
 const login = async () => {
        let bool = false;
        await axios.post(url + '/login', {
            username: form.email,
            password: form.password
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            if (response.data === 202) {
                bool = !bool;
                console.log(bool);
            } else if (response.data === 404) {
                console.log(bool);
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
        return bool;
    }
```

**The Button**

```
<Button onClick={() => login() && onClose()} color="primary"> Login </Button>
```

**I have also tried ternary operators with the same result**

```
 <Button onClick={() => login() ? onClose() : null} color="primary"> Login </Button>
```

**Thanks to @pilchard the right way is**

```
<Button onClick={async () => await login() && onClose()} color="primary">Login</Button>
```

Comment: You would need to `await login()`. As it stands `login()` returns a promise immediately, which evaluates as truthy. `onClick={async () => await login() && onClose()}`

Comment: This seems like a very strange pattern.  Maybe `onClose` should be called in a `useEffect` triggered by some state change made by `login`.  Or maybe `login` should take a `callback` as an argument and call it on success.

Comment: @pilchard That was it! thank you so much!